# How to find the zeros of $5-2x$ and $x+10$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to find all the zeros for: 
$$f(x)=-2x^3-9x^2+95x-150$$ 
So far I have figured out that it factors out to

$$(x-3)(5-2x)(x+10)$$

but I can't figure out how to find the zeros of

$$5-2x$$ and $$x+10$$

Comment: Equate those factors to $0$ and solve for $x$.

Comment: So, what's the solutions of $5-2x = 0$?

Comment: How do you know the zeros of $g(x)=(x-3)?$

Answer (score 0):

Notice, equating the factors $(5-2x)$ & $(x+10)$ to zero as follows $$5-2x=0$$$$2x=5\implies x=\color{red}{\frac{5}{2}}$$
&
$$x+10=0$$ $$\implies x=\color{red}{-10}$$